# How internal linking works and why I get the same value for the two objects?

Tags: c++, internal-link

I am trying to understand internal linking and external linking so I've tried this program:

```
// foo.h
static int x = 7; // makes x internally linked
void print();

// foo.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

// bar.h
static int x = 5; // internally linked. without "static" itis linked externally
void func();

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

// driver program
    #include <iostream>

// forward declarations
void func();
void print();


int main()
{
    func();
    print();
}
```

- I've removed inclusion guards (or #pagma once) for the sake of brevity. I also forward-declare `func()` and `print()` functions because if I include the headers they are defined in `foo.h` and `bar.h` then the compiler won't compile because of the redefinition of the object `x`.
- When I run the program I always get always the same value from the two functions `func` and `print` although they reference a separate object `x`.

The output:

```
5
5
```

Normally `print` prints `7` because includes `foo.h` which is initializing its `x` object to `7`.

- I've declared `x` in both headers as `static` to be linked internally in the TU it is used otherwise if remove `static` from them then the two objects has external linking which causes the linker fail because of multiple definitions for the object `x`.

Comment: I think you have an error in the posted code: both foo.cpp and bar.cpp have `func` and `print` is not defined anywhere, only declared. Did you mean for foo.cpp or bar.cpp to have the `print` function instead of `func`?

Comment: If the two routines would also print out the `&x` address of x, you'll note that they are at different addresses.

Comment: Both of your `.cpp` files appear to include `bar.h`. `foo.h` never get compiled. So, your question is...?

Comment: Try renaming the copies of `func` and `print` to `func1` and `func2` and `print1` and `print2` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code but with `foo.cpp` as

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void print()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

and the output is

```
5
7
```

as you expect, so I think that you have a typo in `foo.cpp`.